# Затирается стиль css

Tags: html

Нашел в интернетах стиль, скопировал его. Далее пытаюсь изменить под свои нужды, а именно, хочу чтобы у таблицы заголовок оставался на месте при скроллинге. Нашел соответствующий код тут -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168521/table-fixed-header-and-scrollable-body

```
.tableFixHead {
overflow: auto;
height: 300px;
}
.tableFixHead thead th {
position: sticky;
top: 0;
z-index: 1;
}
```

}

Но у меня заголовок по прежнему уезжает наверх. Видимо, где то перпределяется это поведение, но где я понять не могу. С css знаком пару дней. За помощь буду благодарен. Весь код css:

```
body{
background: black;
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: 400;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: .1em;
}

.content-table {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border-collapse: collapse;
font-size: 0.9em;
min-width: 400px;
border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
overflow: hidden;
box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.content-table thead tr {
position: sticky;
top: 0;
z-index: 1;
background-color: #ca6a00;
color: #ffffff;
text-align: left;
font-weight: bold;
}

.content-table th,
.content-table td {
padding: 12px 15px;
position: sticky;
top: 0;
z-index: 1;
}

.content-table tbody tr {
border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.content-table tbody tr:nth-of-type(even) {
background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

.content-table tbody tr:last-of-type {
border-bottom: 2px solid orange;
}

.content-table tbody tr.active-row {
font-weight: bold;
color: orange;
}

.tableFixHead {
overflow: auto;
height: 300px;
}

.tableFixHead thead th {
position: sticky;
top: 0;
z-index: 1;
}
```

Код html:

```
<div class="tableFixHead">
<table class="content-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            //хедеры
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    текст
                </td>

                <td>
                    текст
                </td>

                <td>
                    текст
                </td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>//хедеры</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```